# how do I add an item on array of Objects on setState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating arrays of objects and storing it on variables like this:

```
const nameOption = nameOptions(listHotels);
const estadoOption = stateOptions(listHotels);
const cityOption = cityOptions(listHotels);
```

my state is currently like this:

```
selectFilter: [
      { id: 1, type: 'Name'},
      { id: 1, type: 'Estado'},
      { id: 1, type: 'Cidade'},
    ],
```

I want to add these variables in a property called "options", like so:

```
selectFilter: [
          { id: 1, type: 'Name', options: nameOption},
          { id: 1, type: 'Estado', options: estadoOption},
          { id: 1, type: 'Cidade', options: cityOption},
        ],
```

how do I do it using the immutable react way?

Comment: You have to create a new array and replace the old one

Answer (score 2):

First store the values to be inserted into a plain object, where the properties match the `type` values of `selectFilter` :

```
const options = {
    Name: nameOptions(listHotels),
    Estado: stateOptions(listHotels),
    Cidade: cityOptions(listHotels)
}
```

Then merge that with `selectFilter` into the extended version of it:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    selectFilter: prevState.selectFilter.map(filter => 
        ({...filter, options: options[filter.type]})
    )
}));
```

NB: there is probably a more efficient way to build the `options` object, since you seem to iterate `listHotels` for each property. This could probably be done in one sweep using `reduce`. But without details about what these functions (`nameOptions`, `stateOptions`, ...) do there is not much I can offer for that. Look into calling `listHotels.reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign()` to duplicate your state into an new object. This object is now mutable. Once done modifying it, you then replace your entire state with the new version. Here is an example of how that could be done.

```
  handleChange= () => {
    let mutableState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    mutableState.thingToChange = foo;
    this.setState(mutableState);
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

```
this.setState(({selectFilter}) => (
    [
         {...selectFilter[0], options: nameOptions},
         {...selectFilter[1], options: estadoOptions},
         {...selectFilter[2], options: cityOptions},
    ]
);
```

Comment: You should really put an explanation here.